# focus a tags with JS

Tags: javascript, tags

Did anyone knew how a tags in the browser are indexed?

I have in my html page 12 items wich are created with a tags, the problem is that when I want to focus the first tag with 
 document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].focus();  the browser don't focus the first item! and if I just want to focus the third item by  document.getElementsByTagName("a")[2].focus();                  it focuses the item number 5.
I am wandering why I have this problem since in my page I have only the wanted items to be focused by a tags and the other html items are div and img tags!

Thanks a lot in advance for your help and reply :)

here is an exmaple of 2 items created in my html page:

```
<div id="carousel_items">
<div id="indicators" class="carousel-indicators" style="visibility: visible;">
  <div id="nextBtn" class="right_indicator">
     <img id="indicators_right" src="images/nextbtn.gif"   style="width:45px;height:25px;">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="div_slides" class="thumbnailList_slides">
   <div class="div_vid">
      <a id="btn0" class="btn_vid" href="#" onclick="javascript:activate('0');">    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="div_vid">
      <a id="btn1" class="btn_vid" href="#" onclick="javascript:activate('1');">  </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share some HTML code?

Comment: @BALAJI do you have an idea please? Thanks :)

Comment: You can use ids also, like `document.getElementById("btn"+var1).focus();` Where var1 can any number.

Answer (score 0):

Elements are returned in the order in which they appear in the DOM.

Various things can make that order different to the order you see them when viewing from left-right and top-bottom including:

- text direction
- float: right
- CSS positioning
- Flex order

Comment: At first thanks for your quick answer! The problem is that the items are positioned with float:left ! so I think it is not related to the CSS positioning.